# Compare XSL values in array

Tags: arrays, xml, variables, xslt, parameters

I'm not sure how to title this post..

I want to compare pubDate between rows

> Desired Output: Only print the pubDate when it is different from the previous row's pubDate. (my substring function returns Dec 2014, Jan 2015, etc)

Currently I have it set to print the pubDate every time.  I just can't figure out how to compare the value between rows... please help!

Code excerpt:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
<xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
<xsl:variable name="item_link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="item_title" select="description"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$Rows"/>
<xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
<xsl:variable name="PrevPosition" select="position()-1" />
<xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
<xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
<xsl:if test="not(substring(pubDate,3,9) = 0)">
  <div align="center">
    <hr/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(pubDate,3,9)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
<li>
  <a href="{$item_link}" title="{$item_title}">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
      <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
        <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

Here is the full code for anybody who wants it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ddwrt msxsl rssaggwrt"
           xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
           xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
           xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart">

<xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">30</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">true</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
<xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
<div>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rss/channel">
<xsl:variable name="link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="description" select="description"/>

<ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
</ul>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
<xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
<xsl:variable name="item_link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="item_title" select="description"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$Rows"/>
<xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
<xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
<xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
<xsl:if test="not(substring(pubDate,3,9) = 0)">
  <div align="center">
    <hr/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(pubDate,3,9)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
<li>
  <a href="{$item_link}" title="{$item_title}">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
      <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
        <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="title"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </a>
</li>




</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
  <xsl:param name="Html"/>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
     <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't know the answer when I don't know what the question is. Try adding an input and desired output.

Comment: Formatting has nothing to do with it.  You do not show us the input XML, so there is no way for anyone here to help you.  If you do so, I expect you will get your answer quickly.

Comment: I am just very lost and new to XSL and it was quite frustrating to immediately get down voted and referred to the rule book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the value of previous "row" you can use the [preceding-sibling](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/12/20/xpathaxes.html) axis operator.

So, instead of writing this....

```
<xsl:if test="not(substring(pubDate,3,9) = 0)">
```

Write this...

```
<xsl:if test="not(substring(pubDate,3,9) = 0) and not(pubDate = preceding-sibling::item[1]/pubDate)">
```

Note the use of the `[1]` here. Doing `preceding-sibling` will return all nodes preceding the current one, and you only want the first one.

Also note, you might be tempted to write this...

```
<xsl:if test="not(substring(pubDate,3,9) = 0) and pubDate != preceding-sibling::item[1]/pubDate">
```

But this will not work for the first `item` element, because for that expression to be true the preceding sibling would have to exist.

Finally, this will only really work if the `item` elements are in `pub-date` order. A better approach would be to consider this a grouping problem, and group the items by date. For XSLT 1.0 you would use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: Muenchian Grouping was the key.  Thank you very much for suggesting it